# KivyMd Calculator using Dropdown Menus

Tags: python, kivy, calculator, kivymd

> I am trying to figure out how to make a basic calculator type app
> using dropdown menus as a way to select different variables. The code
> below is a sample of what I have been working on. I need to get
> object1's value and divide it by object2's value and then display the
> answer on the kivy card below. If anyone knows how this can be done
> some help or an example would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu



class Test(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string("KV")


KV = '''
BoxLayout:
    orientation:'vertical'

    MDBottomNavigationItem:
        MDRaisedButton:
            id: button1
            text: "Object"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .85}
            size_hint: .4, .05
            on_release: app.menu.open()


        MDRaisedButton:
            id: button2
            text: "Object2"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .45}
            size_hint: .4, .05
            on_release: app.menutools.open()
            
        MDCard:
            size_hint: None, None
            size: "280dp", "100dp"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .2}


'''


class Test(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.screen = Builder.load_string(KV)

        menu_items = [
            {"text": "1"},
            {"text": "2"},
            {"text": "3"},
            {"text": "4"},
        ]


        menu_items2 = [
            {"text": "1"},
            {"text": "2"},
            {"text": "3"},
            {"text": "4"},
        ]





        self.menu = MDDropdownMenu(
            caller=self.screen.ids.button1,
            items=menu_items,
            width_mult=5,

        )



        self.menutools = MDDropdownMenu(
            caller=self.screen.ids.button2,
            items=menu_items2,
            width_mult=5,
        )


        self.menu.bind(on_release=self.menu_callback)

    def menu_callback(self, instance_menu, instance_menu_item):
        print(instance_menu, instance_menu_item)

    def build(self):

        return self.screen


Test().run()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It will be easier to answer your question if you provided a minimal working example of what you are trying to do rather than posting your full code. See this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Here is my variant:

## a bit longer but it will do the work

from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu

KV = '''
MDScreen:
MDFillRoundFlatButton:
id: button1
text: "1st Value"
pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .85}
on_press: app.menu1.open()

```
MDFillRoundFlatButton:
    id: button2
    text: "2nd Value"
    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .75}
    on_press: app.menu2.open()

MDFillRoundFlatButton:
    id: solution
    text: "Calculate !"
    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .65}
    on_press: app.calc()
    
MDLabel:
    id: texti
    text: "Result"
    halign: "center"
    font_size: 60

MDFillRoundFlatButton:
    text: "Exit"
    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .35}
    on_release: app.get_running_app().stop()
     
MDCard:
    orientation: "vertical"
    padding: "8dp"
    size_hint: None, None
    size: "280dp", "180dp"
    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .15}

    MDLabel:
        text: "Result"
        theme_text_color: "Secondary"
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1]

    MDSeparator:
        height: "1dp"

    MDLabel:
        text: texti.text
```

'''

values = [0,0]

class Test(MDApp):
def **init**(self, **kwargs):
super().**init**(**kwargs)
self.screen = Builder.load_string(KV)
menu_items_1 = [
{
"text": f"{i}",
"viewclass": "OneLineListItem",
"on_release": lambda x=i: self.menuc1(x),
} for i in range(1,5)
]
menu_items_2 = [
{
"text": f"{i}",
"viewclass": "OneLineListItem",
"on_release": lambda x=i: self.menuc2(x),
} for i in range(1,5)
]

```
    self.menu1 = MDDropdownMenu(
        caller=self.screen.ids.button1,
        items=menu_items_1,
        width_mult=4,
    )
    self.menu2 = MDDropdownMenu(
        caller=self.screen.ids.button2,
        items=menu_items_2,
        width_mult=4,
    )

def menuc1(self, text_item):
    global values
    values[0] = int(text_item)
    print(values)
    
def menuc2(self, text_item):
    global values
    values[1] = int(text_item)
    print(values)

def calc(self,pre = 4):
    global values
    self.screen.ids.texti.text = f'{round(values[0]/values[1], pre)}' if values[0] != 0 and values[1] != 0 else self.screen.ids.texti.text
    print(values)

def build(self):
    return self.screen
```

Test().run()

Comment: And sorry for the format but is my first time posting here (•‿•)